# Which parameter do I need to pass for user registration?

Tags: 7, services

I have first name, lastname, email, password, confirmed password and gender
for user registration like facebook registration when I visit https://example.com/my_services/user/register.

Then I get the error "You are not allowed to change your username" when I select put method. How do I find the keys of that fields so that I send key and values?

I don't know which parameter I need to send with the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_data["field_name_first"]["en"][0]["value"]='testranjeet8';
$user_data["field_name_last"]["und"][0]["value"]='testgholave8';
$user_data["mail"]="testranjeet12@example.com";
$user_data["pass"]["pass1"]="test123458";
$user_data["pass"]["pass2"]="test123458";
$user_data["field_gender"]["en"]="Male";
```

Just pass the parameter you will get the result .I had problem with android side that they are not passing value correctly 
finally i got answer

Answer (score 0):

Sample JSON that you can use with poster:

```
{
    "name": "priya1",
    "pass": "priya1",
    "pass1": "priya1",
    "pass2": "priya1",
    "mail": "priya1@gmail.com",
    "conf_mail": "priya1@gmail.com",
    "field_name_first": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "ranjeet"
            }
        ]
    },
    "field_name_last": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "gholave"
            }
        ]
    },
    "roles": [
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
}
```

[image: firefox Poster]